Seeking Guidance on Achieving Extensive Control Over Webots Scene Elements
I need extensive control over the scene elements in Webots. My goal is to modify and move scene nodes, access sensors from multiple robots, and control the timestep in a centralized way. Does the custom windows feature allow for the extensive interaction and manipulation I need? I've been using the Supervisor node, but its capabilities seem limited. Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
